# "ReadFile Function" is there a way that I can no longer declare specific number of bytes to be read?

Tags: c++, api, readfile, createfile, writefile

I'm trying to make a program using windows API in C++
The goal is to read the content of the text file that I've created and able to manipulate the content using bitwise XOR (change to lowercase and uppercase, vice versa) then put the manipulated content again inside of a text file.
Here the flow of the program that I've used:

1. Open text file using CreateFile.
2. Put the content of the text file on a created malloc.
3. Manipulate the content of the text file using bitwise XOR (xor = 20).
4. Then put the xor value to the text file again.

Here's the code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HANDLE openFile;
    HANDLE ovewriFile;
    BOOL readwriFile;
    DWORD dwNoByteRead = 0;
    DWORD dwNoByteWritten = 0;
    char *strVal;
    //allocate memory
    strVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strVal));
    memset(strVal, '0x00', sizeof(strVal));

    //open a file
    openFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\John.Doe\\Documents\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    //reading the content
    readwriFile = ReadFile(openFile, strVal, 34, &dwNoByteRead, NULL);
    cout << "original content is " << strVal << endl;

    CloseHandle(openFile);

    //manipulate data using xor
    for (int i = 0; i != strlen(strVal); i++) {
        if (strVal[i] == 0x20)
        {
            continue;
        }
        strVal[i] ^= 0x20;
    }
    cout << "xor value: " << strVal << endl;

    //overwrite a file
    ovewriFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\farrel.moje\\Documents\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    //write the content
    readwriFile = WriteFile(ovewriFile, strVal, 34, &dwNoByteWritten, NULL);

    //just a way to know if successful yung writefile
    if (readwriFile == FALSE) {

        cout << "ERROR WRITING " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Success Overwrite " << endl;
    }
    cout << "Modified content " << strVal << endl;

    CloseHandle(ovewriFile);
    free(strVal);

    return 0;
}
```

This program is working but when I tried to change the nNumberOfBytesToRead (The maximum number of bytes to be read) from 34 to sizeof(strVal) or strlen(strVal)

readwriFile = ReadFile(openFile, strVal, 34, &dwNoByteRead, NULL);

but using sizeof and strlen, it didn't show the full content of the text file.
Is there a way that I can no longer declare specific number of bytes to be read?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you using `malloc` ?

Comment: I dont think this has enough memory to hold the contents of your file `strVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strVal));`

Comment: just for familiarization of using malloc @user463035818

Comment: `sizeof(strVal)` is equal to `sizeof (char*)`, which is equal to 4, or 8, on most systems. Why did you think, that would be equivalent to 34?

Comment: in the same line of argumentation you could use `goto` just for the sake of getting familiar with `goto`. Just dont do it. There are rare cases where you need to use `malloc` in c++. I didnt encounter any yet

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius yeah I actually think of that, I tried to test that theory and it showed only 4 characters when using sizeof(strVal)

Comment: you are allocating memory for 4 characters and then write the contents of a file to that location. If your file has more then 4 characters your program has undefined behaviour. It seems to work, but strictly speaking it does not

Comment: @user463035818 yeah, I've already test that, it only show 4 characters. So the problem here is the initiation of malloc?

Comment: @nwb1027 1) "_and it showed only 4 characters when using `sizeof(strVal)`_" Since `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time (opposed to the runtime), the result would be the same, regardless of when you invoked it (prior to writing to said array, or after). 2) If you wrote more than 4 bytes to such an array, you are invoking undefined behavior, due to writing past the end of allocated memory.

Comment: frankly, the problem is that you are messing around with manual memory allocations when there is no obvious reason to do so. `strVal` should probably be a properly sized `std::string` or `std::vector`

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius ok understand. I'm actually thinking what would be the appropriate operator to be use in order to get the size of the array?

Comment: @nwb1027 But, `strVal` is not an array. It's a pointer.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I mean is there a way to get the size of the value of the pointer?

Comment: Use [`GetFileSizeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfilesizeex) to get the size of the input file?

Comment: Multiple bugs.  The one not yet mentioned is that ReadFile() is low-level and merely reads bytes.  It does not in any way try to produce a valid C string, you have to append the zero-terminator yourself.  dwNoByteRead tells you where to put it.

Comment: @nwb1027 "_I mean is there a way to get the size of the value of the pointer?_" The pointer points to a `char`. Hence the size of the value pointed to by a pointer is `sizeof (char)`. Yes, the pointer might point to the first element of the array, but there is no way of figuring out if the pointer is to a single element (`char a; char* pa = &a; char* p = new char;`), or to a first element, of a sequence of elements (`char* p = new char[10];`). If you can't even distinguish that, you can't distinguish the size (or amount) of memory allocated.

Comment: @shan `strVal` is a pointer. Pointer size is typically 4 or 8 bytes on currently available hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Remove yours

```
strVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(strVal));
memset(strVal, '0x00', sizeof(strVal));
```

because it's a bad idea.

Change some code to get size of your file:

```
openFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\John.Doe\\Documents\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

LARGE_INTEGER fs;
GetFileSizeEx(openFile, &fs);
unsigned long long fSize = fs.QuadPart;
strVal = new char[fSize+1];
memset(strVal, 0, fSize+1);

//reading the content
readwriFile = ReadFile(openFile, strVal, fSize, &dwNoByteRead, NULL)
```

And at the end don't forget to

```
delete []strVal;
```

instead of yours *free(strVal)*

Comment: In C++ there is almost no reason to use `new` and most certainly no reason ever to call `delete`. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, captain)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the API GetFileSizeEx() to get the File size first.
Also, sizeof(point) always return 4/8 because it's the size of this point, but not the size you want allocate.
Add and change your code like below:

```
LARGE_INTEGER liFileSize;
//open a file
openFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\John.Doe\\Documents\\test.txt", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
GetFileSizeEx(openFile, &liFileSize);
//allocate memory
strVal = (char*)malloc(liFileSize.QuadPart);
memset(strVal, 0, liFileSize.QuadPart);
```

Then You can use "liFileSize.QuadPart" to replace the "nNumberOfBytesToRead"（34）

Comment: You explained, what's wrong with the OP's code, but then decided to do *the same thing*. `sizeof(liFileSize.QuadPart)` evaluates to 8.

Comment: @IInspectable ,Sorry for my written mistake, and I have fixed it .

Comment: No, you haven't. You merely introduced *more* undefined behavior.