# Reading a .txt file using a struct data structure without knowing the size of the structure needed

Tags: c++

I need to read data from a .txt file into C++ using the struct data structure. I can do this fine; however, if I don't know the initial size of the data structure needed, what would I do then?
For example, you normally need to define your structure like "Points[20]" if you have 20 pieces of data. 
So, is there a way to read a .txt file of any size into a struct data structure?
I have had a look on the site but can't find any question similar to mine.

Comment: You may use a `std::vector<MyStruct>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295951/readfile-function-is-there-a-way-that-i-can-no-longer-declare-specific-number

Comment: @PaulSanders that question is the whole file as one big block of bytes, not as structures. And the answers are of pretty bad quality.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that's why I didn't vote to close as a duplicate.  It might be vaguely helpful to the OP though - it's not obvious how he proposes to map whatever is in his .txt file to structs in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question has some bad assumptions. It would be better with a more specific example and a code attempt to go off of in order to make sure the OP's concerns are addressed.

However, I can answer that:

- A data structure can be a struct or a class or aggregates thereof
- A data structure can be made with dynamic sizing or dynamic sizing members
- It is important to come up with a specification for your files and the data structures that the file will be deserialized into

For example:

I could say that I will create a file that contains

- A leading byte defining how many values will follow, representing an unsigned number 0-255
- A number of values one byte each, ranging from 0 - 255

Then I could easily create a parse method that stuffed them into an std::vector of char or std::vector of unsigned or some other dynamic sizing container.

I may or may not create a struct that wraps the vector and the Parse method.

There certainly isn't one way of doing things, but the main point here is that you are looking for **dynamically** sized containers

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the structure of the text file, only a general answer can be given.

**CSV Files**
Many text files are organized as columns (fields) and rows (records).  The columns are separated by commas, tabs, vertical bars or other separated characters.  Too many duplicates on StackOverflow, so search the internet for "C++ read CSV".

**HTML & XML**
Some text files have data organized like a tree structure, with records of records.  Examples are HTML and XML.  Use a library to read these.

**Online Judge**
These text files contain data for a programming problem.  Usually they have one row for the number of test cases, then followed by data for each test case.  The organization of the data is problem specific.

**Other**
Text file can have their data in any, arbitrary, format.  You'll need to contact the producer of the data for the layout.

**Dynamic Data Quantity**
In many instances, the quantity of the data records is not known at compile time.  You'll need a *dynamically sized container*, such as `std::vector, std::list, std::map,` etc.